# Using Pip and Importing Packages in Python 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, twilio

I'm on Lubuntu (a minimal build of Ubuntu). I installed Python 3.6.1 with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

I want to use Twilio, so I tried this:

```
pip install twilio
```

It said pip wasn't recognized, so I ran this, followed by the above again:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

I fired up Python 3.6 and tried importing it, but that didn't work out:

```
>>> from twilio.rest import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I'm new to python3 (which I want to use for the `secrets` module), Ubuntu, and twilio, so I'm not really sure what's going on here. I'd think if it was as simple as a module not being found, the stack trace would be much shorter... I'm not sure if the stack trace is so long because maybe Python 3 produces longer ones than 2 did, or Ubuntu is trying to do something weird because both Python 2 and 3 are installed (and perhaps two versions of 3 at that), or if maybe this is the work of twilio?

Comment: Are you sure you installed pip correctly? From my experience, you usually install pip with the get-pip.py script.

Comment: @travisjayday - I am not. Yeah... maybe I should have done something more cross platform instead of trying something Ubuntu specific, particularly when I have so little experience with Ubuntu...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about this `sudo apt install python-pip` command of yours. Usually you download the `get-pip.py` script from `https://bootstrap.pypa.io` and that works on all platforms.

Comment: @travisjayday - These days, isn't `pip` just part of a standard Python install now? I was surprised when I got the error message from Ubuntu saying it didn't recognize the command.

Comment: Well apparently it's not a default package because it wasn't installed on your system. I've recently set up a Raspberry Pi and the Raspbian OS didn't have it installed either, so my guess is that it's not installed by default (although that might not be the case for some other distros).

Comment: You appear to have a broken Ubuntu Apport installation too, breaking the exception hook it installs (making your tracebacks needlessly noisy).

Comment: Next, for Ubuntu there'll be a separate python3-pip package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-pip&searchon=names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following to download pip:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Then install pip by running:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Then you can install twilio with pip

```
sudo pip3 install twilio
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I replaced `python3` with `python3.6` and `pip3` with `pip3.6`, just btw. It appears to have worked now (or at least simply importing no longer generates a stack trace.) I'll accept this answer as soon as StackOverflow allows it (I don't think I've ever been blocked from accepting an answer other than mine because it was posted too quickly before...)

Comment: Python 3.6 comes with the `ensurepip` module already: `python3 -m ensurepip` would install `pip` for Python 3.